# Error trying to add widgets to QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget

I wanted to make a window and add a QTabWidgets with the widgets I want to it. So I followed the Qt TabDialog example and from what I know, I followed the same path as in the example.
Problem is I get this error while trying to add my widgets as tabs: "/home/user/Programming/C++/QtTests/TabExample/TabExample-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Release/../TabExample/tabwidget.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to 'QTabWidget::addTab(Tab_One*, QString*&)'". Why do I get this error because Tab_One is inherited from QWidget? Here is my main widget code:

Header file:

```
#ifndef TABWIDGET_H
#define TABWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class QTabWidget;
class Tab_One;
class Tab_Two;
class QString;
class QHBoxLayout;
class QDialog;

class TabDialog : public QDialog {
    Tab_One *firstTab;
    Tab_Two *secondTab;
    QTabWidget *myTabWidget;
    QString *labelTabOne;
    QString *labelTabTwo;
    QHBoxLayout *layout;
public:
    TabDialog(QWidget *parent = NULL);
};

#endif // TABWIDGET_H
```

and source file:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QString>

#include "tabwidget.h"
#include "tab1.h"
#include "tab2.h"

TabDialog::TabDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    labelTabOne = new QString("My First Tab");
    labelTabTwo = new QString("My Second Tab");

    myTabWidget = new QTabWidget;

    firstTab = new Tab_One;
    secondTab = new Tab_Two;

    myTabWidget->addTab(firstTab, labelTabOne);
    myTabWidget->addTab(secondTab, labelTabTwo);

    layout->addWidget(myTabWidget);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

and here is one of my widets(tab1):
header:

```
#ifndef TAB1_H
#define TAB1_H

#include <QWidget>
class QVBoxLayout;
class QPushButton;

class Tab_One : public QWidget {
    QPushButton *button_one;
    QPushButton *button_two;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;

public:
    Tab_One(QWidget *parent = NULL);
};

#endif // TAB1_H
```

and source:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QTabWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QString>

#include "tabwidget.h"
#include "tab1.h"
#include "tab2.h"

TabDialog::TabDialog(QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
    layout = new QHBoxLayout;

    labelTabOne = new QString("My First Tab");
    labelTabTwo = new QString("My Second Tab");

    myTabWidget = new QTabWidget;

    myTabWidget->addTab(new Tab_One(this), labelTabOne);
    myTabWidget->addTab(new Tab_Two(this), labelTabTwo);

    layout->addWidget(myTabWidget);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

Thank you very much and sorry for the long post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't your tab, but the QString. `QTabWidget::addTab()` expects a const reference to a QString, but you're giving it a pointer to a QString. Try using the dereference operator (`*`), like this:

```
myTabWidget->addTab(firstTab, *labelTabOne);
myTabWidget->addTab(secondTab, *labelTabTwo);
```